# Nightwatch JS, describe difference between .before(ms) and .after(ms)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, assertion

I am confused about the meaning of/difference between the `.before()` and `.after()` methods when used with the `[expect][1]` assertion.

The docs say that:

> These methods perform the same thing which is essentially retrying the
>   assertion for the given amount of time.

So, is it as simple as that?

They are exactly the same, and interchangeable?

Or is there some difference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code examples:

`browser.expect.element('#main').text.to.contain('The Night Watch').before(1000)`

This is saying that up to 1000 ms after the element('#main') is found, the text will be this value.  Nightwatch will retry the comparison during that 1000ms interval.  The retry rate defaults to 500 ms (the default `waitForConditionPollInterval` value), so this effectively checks the text 2 or 3 times - at 0ms (maybe), 500ms, and 1000ms.

The .after(500) method would check for the value at the 500ms mark only.

I haven't tested this, and could be wrong.  I'd welcome any corrections...

Comment: Seems about right. I haven't tested it either but this is how I would expect it to work.

Comment: This isn't true. Like the docs say, the methods are the same. You can easily test this by having a simple test that uses a `.before` and `.after` - the output indicates how long has elapsed and both numbers will be lower than the time given (assuming they pass). Switching your `.before` calls to `.after` will also have no affect on the results or logged time taken for the test.